# One line way to assign values to an array of structure?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, data-structures

In VB.net, is there a way to assign values to an array of structure in a single line?  For example if I have an array of structure like this:

```
Public Structure CommandInfo
    Public CommandChar As Char
    Public CommandType As String
    Public Description As String    
End Structure
Public CommandSet(NumCommands - 1) As CommandInfo
```

Is there a way to assign values to the array like this:

```
CommandSet(0)={"C", "Initialization", "Initialize pump motor"}
```

Otherwise, I've been having to do a line of code for each structure element for each array element--it's a little ugly.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that if you write your own collection with a custom `Add` routine taking three arguments, you can array syntax like `{{"C", "Initialization", "..."}, {"D", "Deletion", "..."}}` etc.  As a small aside, I'd suggest you turn `Option Strict On`.  You should need to specify the character argument as `"C"C`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CommandSet(0) = New CommandInfo With {.CommandChar = "C", .CommandType = "Initialization", .Description = "Initialize pump motor"}
```